Broadcast a Firebase message to an unreleased version
I have Firebase integrated into my app. I've build a new version and want to target it during a messaging campaign. Before releasing it I'd like to test the targeted messaging along with the receiving end, however I can't find the new version in the Firebase Messaging Console. The app has been in use for some time already. Crashlytics has picked up the new version, though Messaging has not.
Is it even possible now to send messaging broadcasts to unreleased versions of the app? It lets to do so with iOS. What about Android?
